# 'boolean android.webkit.webview.cangoback()' on a null object reference on backpressed - on multilevel fragments (Bottom tab fragment and webview)

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, webview

I have an app where I display a webview and for navigation use the bottom tab, where in one of the bottom fragments (Receivable Fragment) I have 3 buttons to go to different webview fragments (invoiceFragment, pay Fragment and CardFragment). When I set onBackPressed only 1 fragment can run properly (payFragment).

This our onBackPressed function
'public void onBackPressed() {

```
    if (bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.menu_home) {

        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            Log.e(TAG, "kembali webview ");
        } else {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage("Anda Yakin Ingin Keluar?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Tidak",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    } else if (bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.menu_piutang) {
        if (webViewPay.canGoBack() || webViewCard.canGoBack() ) {
                webViewPay.goBack();
                Log.e(TAG, "kembali webview ");
                webViewCard.goBack();
                
        }else{
        int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (backStackEntryCount == 0) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setMessage("Anda Yakin Ingin Keluar?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Tidak",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
            alert.show();
            // write your code to switch between fragments.
        } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        }






    }else if(bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.menu_sales){

        if (webViewSO.canGoBack()) {
            webViewSO.goBack();
            Log.e(TAG, "kembali webview " );
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();

            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    } else {

        if (webViewInv.canGoBack()) {
            webViewInv.goBack();
            Log.e(TAG, "kembali webview ");

        } else {
            int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (backStackEntryCount == 0) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setMessage("Anda Yakin Ingin Keluar?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Ya", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //if user pressed "yes", then he is allowed to exit from application
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Tidak", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //if user select "No", just cancel this dialog and continue with app
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
                // write your code to switch between fragments.
            } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }

            Log.e(TAG, "kembali fragment");
        }
    }
}
```

Bottomnav fragment call :

```
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view);
    bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    //default fragment set - HomeFragment
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
            new HomeFragment()).commit();

    //BackPress settings for Fragment
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .setReorderingAllowed(true)
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, HomeFragment.class, null)
            .commit();

    //bottom navigation

    bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_home:
                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                myToolbar.setTitle("KGS Report");
                break;
            case R.id.menu_sales:
                selectedFragment = new SoFragment();
                myToolbar.setTitle("KGS Report");
                break;
            case R.id.menu_piutang:
                selectedFragment = new PiutangFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.menu_profile:
                selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
        }
        assert selectedFragment != null;
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                selectedFragment).commit();

        return true;
    });

}'
```

And Here my logchat :
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference
at com.kgs.report.MainActivity.onBackPressed(MainActivity.java:119)
at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:3707)
at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2850)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4024)'

I also already define webview public on each fragment.